# Outlook, Config file for users and signatures

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook

I'd like to create a program which format signature in Outlook 2007.

For this, I need know where Names Accounts are located in Windows 7?

I also need to know where is the config file for signatures?

They are saved in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures` in 3 differents formats (txt, htm, rtf). But when I create them manually, they don't appear in Outlook (Options > Courrier > Signatures)